# Smarty:- Create an associative array using for loop and check wheather value exists in array

Tags: php, for-loop, smarty, smarty3

i  am new to smarty and a dont know how to Create an associative array using for loop and check wheather value exists.

But i created the array in php and checked value exists.

Can anyone help me to code the same in smarty tpl file

```
<?php
$newArray=array();
for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++){
$newArray[]=$i;
}
if (in_array("5", $newArray)) 
{ 
echo "found"; 
} 
else
{ 
echo "not found"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
{for $foo=0 to 10}
{$newArray[] = $foo}
{/for}

{if (in_array("5", $newArray))} 
found
{else}
not found
{/if}
```